# What resources exist for designing virtual reality experiences?

Tags: best-practice, virtual-reality, 3d

I'd like to read some resources on VR. Interests include:

- Major 'no-nos' for immersive experiences;
- Design patterns for VR
- Case studies of VR products
- Hidden difficulties with the practicality of creating VR experiences (e.g. moving from 2D assets to 3D)
- How to user test an immersive product
- Usability heuristics for 3D
- Relevant materials from 3D game design
- Where to find academic research or university project writeups
- Openly available VR products to use as benchmarks
- 3D space design guidelines in general

VR is pretty cutting edge, so imagine most of the resources are quite piecemeal, or hidden behind paywalls. That's okay! I'm a patient reader. I'd just like to know if others have discovered anything interesting.

Comment: Here's one of the best collection of VR learning resources I stumbled across. https://uxofvr.com It has links to articles, videos, books and slides too. In particular, I would highly recommend watching Mike Alger's videos. Its concise, very insightful and has some of the best content for VR design. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

I've tried to make this list as non-platform-specific as possible. Keep in mind that any of these links may have a degree of bias towards certain VR headsets, 3D engines, or techniques.

- [Usability and Motion Sickness](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Platforms/VR/ContentSetup/#vrandsimulationsickness)
- [Things to Consider when Creating Content](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Platforms/VR/ContentSetup/#vrcontentconsiderations)
- [Oculus Best Practices (Applies to non-Oculus headsets)](https://developer3.oculus.com/documentation/intro-vr/latest/concepts/book-bp/)
- [VR Design Practices (Specifically "Contextual Reticle" section)](https://blog.marvelapp.com/design-practices-virtual-reality/)

Answer (score 0):

Some thorough guidelines that I can think of right now are:

- Google's guidelines, split up between their [VR app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.vr.cardboard.apps.designlab) and their [written guidelines](https://designguidelines.withgoogle.com/cardboard/)
- Oculus's [best practices](https://developer.oculus.com/design/latest/concepts/book-bp/) write-up
- Intel's [UI guidelines](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/guidelines-for-immersive-virtual-reality-experiences)
- LeapMotion's [VR design guide](http://blog.leapmotion.com/vr-design-guide/)

Other than that, there are lots of articles, videos, and other bite-sized resources online—a good repository of those is at [uxofvr.com](https://uxofvr.com), as recommended by Utsav above.